# Странное поведение QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, файловая-система

В моём приложении дважды используется `QFileDialog` - при выборе плейлиста и mp3 файла.

С недавних пор при вызове `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` начала появляться ошибка **SIGSEGV**. Однако, если вызвать `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` в конструкторе **MainWindow**, то все последующие вызовы этого метода не дают никаких ошибок.

**MediaplayerCfg** - класс, в котором происходит первый вызов QFileDialog

```
class MediaplayerCfg : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:

    void slot_setPosition(int value);
```

mediaplayer.cpp (привёл лишь фрагмент функции, т.к. в остальной части происходит работа лишь с player)

```
void MediaplayerCfg::slot_playTrack()
{
    filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(&wgt,
        tr("Открыть mp3 файл"), QDir::homePath(), tr("mp3 файлы (*.mp3)"));
    qDebug() << filename;

//    filename = "/home/timur/Downloads/Music/Concorde - Just Kiss Her.mp3";

    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename) );
    player->setVolume(50);
```

**TracklistFunctional** - класс для работы с плейлистом 
tracklist.h

```
class TracklistFunctional : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
...
    void parsePlaylist();
};
```

tracklist.cpp

```
// Здесь мы открываем плейлист и записываем пути к трекам в currentTracklist
void TracklistFunctional::parsePlaylist()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(wgt,
        tr("Открыть файл конфигурации"), QDir::homePath(), tr("mp3 файлы (*.mp3)"));

    QFile playList(filename);
    if (playList.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) == false)
    {
        QMessageBox mesError;
        mesError.setText("\tERROR\n"
                         "Playlist can't be open.");
        mesError.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Cancel);
        mesError.exec();
    }

    currentTracklist.clear();
    QTextStream parseStream(&filename);

    QString line;
    while(parseStream.atEnd() )
    {
        line = parseStream.readLine();
        currentTracklist.append(line);
    }

    playList.close();
}
```

Comment: Код, что у вас в вопросе абсолютно валидный, проблема в вашем коде. Локализуйте проблему вплоть до строчки и приложите проблемный код

Comment: Что-то мне не нравится `&wgt`, возможно, в этом и проблема. Попробуйте передавать вместо этого NULL или nullptr. Станет: `QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(nullptr, tr("Открыть mp3 файл"), QDir::homePath(), tr("mp3 файлы (*.mp3)"));`

Comment: Мало того, там в одном месте `&wgt`, а в другом `wgt`.

Comment: @gil9red К сожалению, не помогло

Comment: @vegorov Таким способом пытался хоть как-то исправить ошибку, но не помогло

Comment: @RecursiveDaun, добавьте отладочные строки по всюду и скажите в какой строке случилась проблема

Comment: @gil9red Через дебаг программа падает как раз на строчке QFileDialog (повторно только что проверил). qDebug() говорит о том же

Comment: вместо wgt напишите NULL

Comment: @gil9red К сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в помещении объекта класса **MediaplayerCfg** в новый поток. Из-за этого было нечто вроде борьбы за ресурсы (точно не знаю, что происходило).